# routing in omnichannel

Tags: service-cloud-console, servicecloud, omnichannel

I've setup a Omni channel with all routing configuration. For one of the user, I have assigned the Capacity = 2 with unit of capacity =1. That means my user is available to receive 2 work items if he is available 100% after login to omnichannel.

> **Routing Configuration** :
>
> Available Units of Capacity : 1.00
>
> Routing Priority :    1
>
> Routing Model :    Most Available

My simple issue is when user login to omnichannel, he only receive one open work item (Case) however, there are 4 Cases present in the queue (Routing Configuration already set to this queue).

Can anyone help me to provide what all are the mistake I could have done or anything that I have missed out during setup?

Thanks in advance. Its a bit high priority for me. I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Were other users also logged in the system because if there were four users then everyone should have received one item. But you only accepted and others haven't so system was not able to assign it to you. It will assign it to you only when other users decline the work item that they received for acceptance.

Answer (score 1):

If the cases were in the queue before the queue was assigned to the Routing Configuration, they won't be pushed via Omni. Assigning to a user and then back to the queue should get them in the Omni queue.